# More accurate estimating guitar pitch frequency based on FFT(already) result

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, fft, frequency

I have used FFT algorithm to detect frequency of the sound(guitar pitch) and it works great when I play sinosoidal sound from the computer it will estimate it perfectly but it is not so perfect when i use guitar. How to better estimate the pitch frequency?

```
double[] spectrum = FourierTransform.Spectrum(ref sampleBuffer);//spectrum contains data from FFT
double frequency = indexOfMax(spectrum) * 16000 / 500; //sampling rate/FFT size
//indexOfMax just finds the index of the maximum element in the array
```

To generate sinosoidal waves i used: http://www.audiocheck.net/audiofrequencysignalgenerator_sinetone.php and fort this kind of waves just finding maximum from the spectrum array worked great, but I am looking for better way.

Comment: Is the samplerate and FFT size the same on coming from the Guitar?

Comment: My guess is that you really want the guitar pitch and not the frequency peak, which may be something very different from the musical pitch frequency (could be some nth overtone, etc.)

Comment: @hotpaw2 Yes, I am looking for guitar pitch! : )

Comment: @hotpaw2 How to find it?

Comment: This [Pitch Detector SDK](https://www.littleendian.com/developers/) has been successfully used in guitar tuner apps (for example Kala Tuner for iOS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For guitar sounds, some possibilities for pitch detection/estimation include using the FFT result as the first step of computing the cepstrum for cepstral analysis, or for harmonic product spectrum analysis, or for doing a fast autocorrelation by IFFT(FFT() * conjugate(FFT())).

Comment: That really helps, I am looking for guitar pitch. Could you have or found any example how to find this cepstrum/guitar pitch, may be even pseudo-code. What is conjugate(FFT()). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Automatic pitch determination for musical instruments is non-trivial.

Take a look at this post on the Cepstrum approach to the problem: [Musical instrument Cepstrum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14843124/1984517)